# How to update foreign key in User table Typeorm and Nestjs

Tags: angular, nestjs, typeorm

I have a User Table and an Address Table. Once I have called the post request on the User Table then the Address Table the Foreign Key in the User Table is not updating on Save. The relationship from the User to Address table is ManyToOne as many users can live at the same address. Any suggestion on how to fix this?